# use of jmx in web application

Tags: jmx

can somebody list the uses of JMX in web application other than logging. I am new to JMX and logging seems to be the only good use of JMX.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can you JMX to administer and manage components of a web application.  For starters, most, if not all, Java EE web application servers register a lot of MBeans to provide monitoring and administration capabilities to several of their resources such as, connection pools, transaction managers, deployed applications, etc.  You can then use a JMX client, like JConsole that comes with the JDK/JRE, to attach to a running application server and manage those components.

You can take it one step further, by creating and registering you own, custom MBeans to help manage and control portions of your applications.  As an example, if your web app is using a cache of some kind to boost response times, you could create a control object that is capable of flushing the cache, change entry eviction times, disabling the cache, etc.  Then you could register the control with the MBean server which in turn would make it accessible through the JMX client.

I have done this many times to provide an administration console into my web applications without the need to create any custom user interface.